# Why is Windows apparently using HDD instead of SSD as virtual memory?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, virtual-memory

I'm running a python notebook which is reading big files from disk (stored in HDD) and putting their content into memory.

My computer seems to be using virtual memory, because it is running out of RAM, but it seems to be using the HDD instead of SSD.

Did I understand it correctly, or the 100% read at "Disk 1" is just about data transfer from HDD?

And if it is indeed virtualizing memory into HDD, why does it do that instead of to the SSD? Having a faster virtual memory was probably the primary reason why I put my windows on SSD rather than HDD. I just have 128GB SSD, so I don't store most of my files on it.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your virtual memory settings? How many pagefile.sys files do you have?

Comment: Also note that your computer is ALWAYS using virtual memory, and to some extent the page file, even if you are not already out of ram. the pagefile won't have a lot of current pages from ram in that case, but it does generate some disk activity to maintain. as for why its on your HDD, thats likely because the pagefile is auto-managed and you are short on disk space on the SSD disk. you can override the management to put it wherever you like.

Comment: also for disk at 100%, I don't believe it is transfer/bandwidth. I believe it is the amount of time the disk has queued tasks. Mechanical disks have to scan and seek to a location, read/write the data, and then scan and seek to the next file... so the disk is spending a lot or (perhaps most if the files are small and numerous) of its time locating the file with its heads, rather than sending or receiving data.  as such it queues tasks, and can only perform 1 at a time. if it is never stopping work, that's because the queue is filling up faster than it can complete the tasks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey where do I search for the pagefile.sys file? And where do I check for the virtual memory settings?

Comment: @FrankThomas there were only 2 or 3 .mat (matlab structs) files that were between 100mb to 400mb. Then I took part of them and saved in python pickle format. So there weren't too many files.

Comment: @FrankThomas I have 6GB free in the SSD out of 120GB. Does it decide not to use that?

Comment: if it were me, I sure wouldn't. it may be time to upgrade that SSD to somthing bigger. 120GB is awful confining on a modern PC

Comment: to look at your virtual memory settings, go to control panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Performance (Settings button) > Advamced Tab (Change button) , and look for the drive reporting a page file size that isn't "None". That drive should havce a page file in the root directory. the file is hidden, but if you toggle the view settings you can see it.